# How to call Rest Api endpoints online?How to put my code into real server

Tags: java, rest

I am stating web based project and wrote backend in java, added some REST API endpoints and jsf servlets .I can reach my endpoint in tomcat server through browser but how to put it online, do I have to put my code into real server? (If yes which one) Maybe there are some articles which can explain each steps but I can't find it.

Comment: basically you will need to upload your code (.ear/.war) file to aws/gcp or some other platform.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/host-a-web-app-with-azure-app-service/ this can help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put your work on internet. I think you need to rent a little web server or use your own computer as a server with your home connection